# Calculate the integral via the Laplace function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem: $$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(x+1)\sin 2x}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$
I was able to solve through a Fourier series. It seemed pretty simple to me

**My attempt:**
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(x+1)\sin 2x}{x^2+2x+2}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(x+1)\sin 2x}{(x+1)^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(x+1)\left ( e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix} \right )}{(x+1)^2+1}dx$$
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{F}_x\left [ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right ]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{-ik\xi }}{1+\xi ^2}d\xi =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\left ( \frac{1}{1+i\xi }+\frac{1}{1-i\xi } \right )e^{-ik\xi}d\xi =\\=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\left ( e^{-(1+i\xi )k'}+e^{-(1-i\xi )k'} \right )e^{-ik\xi }d\xi dk'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\iint\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-|k'|-i(k+k')\xi }d\xi dk'=\\=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-|k'|}\delta (k+k')dk'=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|k|}
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{F}_x\left [ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right ]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\xi }{1+\xi ^2}e^{-ik\xi }d\xi =i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|k|}\mathrm{sgn}k\Rightarrow \\\Rightarrow F(k)=\mathcal{F}_x\left [ \frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+1} \right ]=e^{ik}\mathcal{F}_x\left [ \frac{x}{1+x^2} \right ]=-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{|k|+ik}\mathrm{sgn}k
\end{multline*}
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(x+1)\left ( e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix} \right )}{(x+1)^2+1}dx=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left ( F(2)-F(-2) \right )=\frac{\pi}{2e^2}\left ( e^{2i}+e^{-2i} \right )=\frac{\pi}{e^2}\cos 2$$

Question: *How do I solve this integral through Laplace?*

Comment: Maybe: $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{(x+1) \sin (2 x)}{x^2+2 x+2} \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{(1-x) \sin (2 x)}{2-2 x+x^2} \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(x+1) \sin (2
   x)}{x^2+2 x+2} \, dx=\Im\left(\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{(1-x) \exp (2 i x)}{2-2 x+x^2} \, dx\right)+\Im\left(\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(x+1) \exp (2 i x)}{x^2+2 x+2}
   \, dx\right)=\Im\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[-\frac{1-x}{2-2 x+x^2}\right](-2 i)\right)+\Im\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{x+1}{x^2+2 x+2}\right](-2
   i)\right)=\Im\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[-\frac{1-x}{2-2 x+x^2}+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2 x+2}\right](-2 i)\right)$

Comment: Well, what do we do next?

Comment: Calculate  Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is an even easier way:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(x+1)\sin(2x)}{(x+1)^2+1}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x \sin(2x-2)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\cos(2)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(2x)}{x^2+1}\,dx $$
since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\cos(2x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$ exists by Dirichlet's test but equals zero by symmetry. Then

$$ 2\cos(2)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\sin(2x)\,dx = 2\cos(2)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\mathcal{L}(\sin(2x))\,dx $$
by the self-adjointness of the Laplace transform, thus the original integral equals
$$ 2\cos(2)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\cos(s)}{4+s^2}\,ds =2\cos(2)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2t)}{1+t^2}\,dt = \frac{\pi \cos(2)}{e^2},$$
since the function
$$ f(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(a t)}{1+t^2}\,dt $$
defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ fulfills $\lim_{a\to 0^+}f(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f(a)+f'(a)=0$ for any $a>0$.